# Simpify record count query

Tags: mysql

I have a table in the following format.

```
FIELD           TYPE           DATA EXAMPLE
----------------------------------------------
id           |  int(11)     |  123
job          |  int(7)      |  456
date         |  datetime    |  0000-00-00 00:00:00
complete     |  tinyint(4)  |  0 or 1
```

I need to write a query that will go though this large table and count how many records per project per day with with **complete** status 0 and  **complete** status 1.

Because there might be multiple entries on the same day, I thought of first running one query and get unique dates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(date) AS dt
FROM mytable
ORDER BY DATE(date) ASC
```

and then run another query within and do the count

```
SELECT
    SUM(id) AS cnt,
    job,
    DATE(date)
FROM mytable
WHERE complete = 0
AND DATE(date) = '".$uniqueDate."'
GROUP BY job
```

But is is starting to get a bit convoluted because I'll also need to run a second similar query for **complete = 1**

There's gotta be a better way of doing this, hah?..

**UPDATE:**

The data looks somewhat like this:

```
is    job       date                   complete
-----------------------------------------------
234   324234    2011-06-17 06:59:24     0
235   324234    2011-06-17 08:09:22     1
235   544560    2011-06-18 02:51:12     0
244   677234    2012-07-17 11:12:14     1
```

Basically when the initial script will run it will collect the data and insert it into another table in the following format:

```
stat_jobID        (job ID from previous table)
stat_date         (date from previous table)
stat_complete     (count total)
stat_incomplete   (count total)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify with a set of sample input records and the accompanying output rows you expect to produce? You got two different interpretations of your requirement below.

Comment: Updated with clarifications. Thanks.

Comment: So the result should be 1 row for each of those 3 `job` numbers, and `324234` should have 1,1 for `stat_complete, stat_incomplete` while the other two should have `1,0` and `0,1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as `complete` to the `GROUP BY` criteria, so you get each count.

```
SELECT job,
       complete,
       DATE(date) AS report_date,
       COUNT(*)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY job, complete, report_date
```

You could also pivot it, so you get complete and incomplete on the same row:

```
SELECT job,
       SUM(complete >= 1) AS completed,
       SUM(complete = 0) AS not_completed,
       DATE(date) AS report_date
FROM mytable
GROUP BY job, report_date
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/973340/4)

Comment: We're reading the requirement differently, but I think you may be correct - count of each 0/1 per job per day, not count of rows per job with both a 0/1 per day as I interpreted.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. _and_ is somewhat ambiguous the way he used it.

Comment: I tried the second option, as it offers both counts on one pass but I don't think I got the expected results. Here's a snapshot of the output I got: http://imgur.com/JSr13Sm Third column is "job id", than two columns with sums. I'd expect all those with job = 338 be combined in two rows for completed and not, on that particular date. What did I miss?..  Thanks.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle?

Comment: Hmm, sqfiddle. Cool. I tried to put something into: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/973340   I also noticed that complete is not 0 / 1 but rather 0 -100, so I changed my query to be SUM(complete > 0) AS completed,

Comment: Needed to use a different alias for `DATE(date)`. It was grouping by the `date` column in the input table, rather than the alias.